# Import custom font theme into Android Studio Editor\Fonts for IDE

Tags: fonts, android-studio, themes, editor

I am trying to set a custom font theme into Android Studio, I am trying to import a font similar to Menlo from Snow Leopard. The font that I have found is [this](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page).

I don't know how to import a `.tff` file into Android Studio.

This is what I am talking about:

[image]

How would I import a custom font into Android Studio?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't import fonts into Android Studio. Install them into your OS using the normal font installation procedures and they will be accessible to Android Studio the next time you launch it.